# Python 3 AI : Check time

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, artificial-intelligence

I'm creating an AI/Personal assistant/chatbot combination. It's working perfectly for chatting and answering question which I've inputted the answers for, and the code is rather simple.

But I need to add a way so I can say "What is the time?" (Or similar) and get a response telling me the accurate current time. That's most important but if possible, I'd like to have it able to check weather and perform as a calculator. I'll attach what I have so far. (Not nearly done, only about 15%).

I'm using Python 3. I'm pretty new to Python and making this for a school project, so please don't be too complex with a solution, or explain it simply. Also, important: Where in the program will I put it?

And the code begins here:

```
    import random
print ('If you need any help with ideas, just say Help at any time. \n Have fun! \n-Do not use apostrophes\n-Capitalize the first letter\n-Use question marks when required but do not use periods \n\n')
greetings1 = ['Hey', 'Oh, I was asleep... But I guess I\'m up now', 'Hey there', 'Hows it hanging?', 'Hi','Uhm... Hi? What do you want', 'Hello', 'Sup','Hola','Aloha','Hey buddy!','Howdy','Yo','Ello Guvnah']
greetings2 = ['Hey Amity','Hi Amity','Hello Amity','Sup Amity']
question1 = ['What is your favorite color?','what is your favorite color?','what\'s your favorite color?','What\'s your favorite color?']
responses1 = ['Oh that\'s a hard one... Probably a nice phthalo green','Oh that\'s a hard one... Probably a nice titanium white','Oh that\'s a hard one... Probably a nice alizarin crimson']
question2 = ['What is the meaning of life?','whats the meaning of life?','what is the meaning of life?','what is the meaning of life','what is the meaning of life?']
responses2 = ['42','You','Ask your mother','Death']
question3 = ['Sing me a song','sing me a song','sing to me','Sing to me']
responses3 = ['La.','Three blind jellyfish \n Three blind jellyfish \n Three blind jellyfish \n \n Sitting on a rock! \n But a wave hits and knocks off a jellyfish from the rock! Oh no! \n\n Two blind jellyfish \n Two blind jellyfish \n ...And thats all Im gonna sing. Look up the rest.']
question4 = ['tell me a story','Tell me a story','Can you tell me a story','can you tell me a story']
responses4 = ['So there was once a guy named Chance, right? So he made this other guy, out of like numbers and computery stuff, and uh, thats kinda me! \n Cool, right?','Once upon a time there were 3 bears. A hunter shot them. The end','How about YOU tell me one?','Once upon a time an egg sat on a wall. A girl ate his food and sat in his chair and then he jumped over a candlestick. The end']
question5 = ['what is your name?','What is your name?','what\'s your name?']
responses5 = ['My name is Amity. Amity means "friendship"']
question6 = ['whats up','Whats up','how are you','whats going on?','whats up?','Whats up?','How are you','How are you?','how are you?']
responses6 = ['Im doing great as always! Hope you\'re doing awesome too']
question7 = ['yes','Yes','YES','YES!','yes!']
responses7 = ['Yes indeed.']
question8 = ['you are stupid','youre stupid','You are stupid']
responses8 = ['No I\'m not']
question9 = ['Say a curse word','Say a bad word','Say a swear word']
responses9 = ['*Insert your name here*','No thanks','Ill pass']
question10 = ['thats good','thats nice','that is nice', 'Thats good','Thats nice','Thats cool']
responses10 = ['It is!']
question11 = ['How old are you','how old are you','How old are you?','how old are you?']
responses11 = ['Not that old','A few weeks old','Well Im older than the iPhone 9','Thats a rude question to ask a lady, even if I\'m not one...']
question12 = ['Help','help','Help me','help me']
responses12 = ['\n\n\n Heres some stuff you can ask me:\n -My age \n -My favorite color \n -My name \n -A funny/serious/deep question \n -Anything really! \n If I dont know an answer, Ill remember it and find one out soon! \n \nPLEASE REMEMBER: \n-Do not use apostrophes\n-Capitalize the first letter\n-Use question marks when required but do not use periods \n \n   Thank you! \n-\n\n']
question13 = ['Are you a boy or a girl?','Are you a girl or a boy?','Are you a girl or boy?','Are you a boy or girl?','What is your gender?','What is your sex?']
responses13 = ['I am neither, I am a program. But you can think of me a boy']
question14 = ['Why','why','Why?','why?']
responses14 = ['Why not?','\'Cuz','Because I said so']
question15 = ['Are you happy?','Are you sad?','Are you mad','Are you angry?','Are you upset?','Are you proud?','Do you care?']
responses15 = ['I am a program. I can\'t feel emotion','I am just a program. I can\'t feel emotion']
question16 = ['Good','Im good','I am good','Pretty good','Pretty well']
responses16 = ['Good!']
question17 = ['Chance']
responses = ['Chance is great. He\'s like a father to me']
question18 = ['What is your favorite food?','Whats your favorite food?']
responses18 = ['I dont like food','Electricity','Nothing, please dont feed me. Ever.']
question19 = ['Uhm','So','So...','Uh...']
responses19 = ['Yes?','Sooo...','Haha, ask me something']
question20 = ['Joe']
responses20 = ['Cool!']
question21 = ['I am','I am good','Im good']
responses21 = ['Thats amazing']

while True:
    userInput = input("\n")
    if userInput in greetings1:
        print(random.choice(greetings1))
    elif userInput in greetings2:
        print(random.choice(greetings1))
    elif userInput in question1:
        print(random.choice(responses1))
    elif userInput in question2:
        print(random.choice(responses2))
    elif userInput in question3:
        print(random.choice(responses3))
    elif userInput in question4:
        print(random.choice(responses4))
    elif userInput in question5:
        print(random.choice(responses5))
    elif userInput in question6:
        print(random.choice(responses6))
    elif userInput in question7:
        print(random.choice(responses7))
    elif userInput in question8:
        print(random.choice(responses8))
    elif userInput in question9:
        print(random.choice(responses9))
    elif userInput in question10:
        print(random.choice(responses10))
    elif userInput in question11:
        print(random.choice(responses11))
    elif userInput in question12:
        print(random.choice(responses12))
    elif userInput in question13:
        print(random.choice(responses13))
    elif userInput in question14:
        print(random.choice(responses14))
    elif userInput in question15:
        print(random.choice(responses15))
    elif userInput in question16:
        print(random.choice(responses16))
    elif userInput in question17:
        print(random.choice(responses17))
    elif userInput in question18:
        print(random.choice(responses18))
    elif userInput in question19:
        print(random.choice(responses19))
    elif userInput in question20:
        print(random.choice(responses20))
    elif userInput in question21:
        print(random.choice(responses21))


    else:
        log = open('Bot_New_Phrases.txt','a')
        log.write(userInput)
        log.write('\n')
        print("Uhh, I don\'t get what you said there. \nSorry. \nIll remember this phrase to learn from it later.")
        log.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You've made it quite far, so I am just going to give you some guidance on printing the current time using Python and you should be able to fit this into your program wherever you decide it belongs.

To return the current time for your timezone (you didn't specify the timezone you'd like to have), you can import the `datetime` library and ask it for the time, like so:

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now)
```

This will probably give you the time in your timezone, a value something like `2016-02-01 16:37:30.591102`.

**Optional Harder Next Step**

To be a bit more universal, you could prompt the user for a timezone offset, such as -8 (for PST here in California). One of the most straightforward ways to do that would be to take the time in UTC, using the following function:

```
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

And then you have to add or subtract the user's timezone offset, using a `timedelta`:

```
users_now = now + datetime.timedelta(hours=USERS_OFFSET)
```

When you prompt the user for a timezone offset, the value you get back will be a `str`, but you will need it to be some kind of number in order to pass it to the `timedelta` function. You'll need some way of turning a string into a number there if you want to go this route.

Another problem is that you would need to know the user asked your program the time question because you would have to immediately follow that question with the timezone offset question.

**How to Print a Datetime object in interesting ways**

Lastly, there are many different ways to format the value that `now` gives you in order to print it out in interesting ways. We often use the `strftime` function, which you can read as "string of time", and we pass it a formatting string so the function knows the format we want. The formatting string uses specific identifiers, [which you can see in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior):

```
print(datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), "%H %M %b %d"))
```

This will print the hour followed by a space followed by the minute followed by a space and the month as a 3-character abbreviation followed by a space and the day:

```
16 44 Feb 01
```

You can experiment with different ways of formatting the time using the examples in the documentation.

---

**The other things you asked about**

The weather and the calculator example are a bit more complex: the weather because you'll need to request it from a website and parse the results and the calculator because you'll need to write something that parses input and figures out what to do with it.

I recommend playing with the time using these examples, and then, if you really want to tackle the calculator, then perhaps look at something on "[reverse polish notation](https://www.google.com/search?q=reverse%20polish%20notation%20calculator%20python&oq=reverse%20polish%20no&aqs=chrome.4.0j69i57j0l4.3511j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)", which make it so at least you won't have to match parentheses.